# Python Google App Engine: A better way of saying, "If an object does not exist in the datastore, do something"?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am asking because the way I have it right now seems really strange. Basically, I am saying, "If there is an exception thrown, do something. Else, do nothing." Here is some sample code:

```
 try:
        db.get(db.Key(uid))
 except:
        newUser = User(key_name=str(uid)) 
        newUser.first_name = self.request.get("first")
        newUser.last_name = self.request.get("last")
        newUser.email = self.request.get("email") 
        newUser.phone = self.request.get("phone")
        db.put(newUser)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Exceptions are a legitimate way to do flow control, but it's true that they're less efficient than other structures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `User.get_by_key_name(str(uid))` instead. It will return `None` if the entity doesn't exist.

See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_key_name for details.

`User.get_or_insert(str(uid))` might also be a good fit for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Does `db.Key` return `None` if there is no user with the given `uid`? If so, you could just do:

```
if db.Key(uid) == None:
    newUser = User(key_name=str(uid)) 
    newUser.first_name = self.request.get("first")
    newUser.last_name = self.request.get("last")
    newUser.email = self.request.get("email") 
    newUser.phone = self.request.get("phone")
    db.put(newUser)
```

EDIT: going by your comment, you get an exception anyway, so unless you have some other way of checking for nonexistence of a User, you may as well stick with what you have. You could always do it the other way around and put the bulk of the code in the `try` block, though, assuming that an exception will be thrown when trying to add a User with a Key that already exists in the database, like so:

```
try:
    newUser = User(key_name=str(uid)) 
    newUser.first_name = self.request.get("first")
    newUser.last_name = self.request.get("last")
    newUser.email = self.request.get("email") 
    newUser.phone = self.request.get("phone")
    db.put(newUser)
except:
    pass
```

Or something like that.

Comment: It doesn't return None. I get something called BadKeyError. I still feel like my way is an unconventional way.

Comment: @ayanonagon: Updated my answer, then, but it seems hwiechers has what you want.

Comment: BadKeyError is thrown when the key is invalid - not when it's valid but does not exist in the datastore. You need to distinguish between the case when you have an invalid key, and the case when you have a valid but nonexistent key.